# Getting 'Rake Routes' to display what I want

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Routing was always one of the more annoying things to me. Rake routes would display information that I would be able to use, but I wouldn't be able to manipulate the information the way I wanted it to be. In my program, I have a user model, for which I used devise. Each user can create employees, and employees become their own users (with login credentials and such).

I'm having trouble with the employee 'Update' method. The user update method works fine. When I run rake routes, I get the following lines

```
PUT    /users(.:format)                  devise/registrations#update
PUT    /employees/:id(.:format)          employees#update
```

When I try to update my employees, I get the error

```
No route matches [PUT] "/employees"
```

That's the route I want to be able to PUT to, but it looks like rails would rather give me /employees/:id to work with.

My routes file includes

```
devise_for :users
resources :users, :only => [:index, :show, :new, :edit, :create, :update, :destroy]
resources :employees, :only => [:index, :show, :new, :edit, :create, :update, :destroy]
```

Any help would be great, and any additional information on manipulating my routes would be splendid. Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here's my update employee controller method

```
  def update
    @employee = current_company.users.find(params[:id])
    if @employee.update_attributes(params[:employee])
      redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @employee.id
      flash[:notice] = "Employee information updated"
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
      flash[:notice] = "No edits were made"
    end
  end
```

Comment: I added my update method to the post. Does this tell rails the employee it needs to update? I think it does. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, that updates an employee. But you are using `params[:id]` there, so you should do a put request to `/employees/:id`, not to `/employees`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to update an employee, Rails has to know which employee to update and for that you need an id. If you don't need an id, you should set up a default route instead of `resources :employees`:

```
put '/employees', :to => 'employees#update'
```

By the way, why are you using `:only` and then list all the possible actions? You don't need `:only` if you want all the actions. If you use the custom route above you may want to exclude the update action from resources. For that you can use `:except`:

```
resources :employees, :except => :update
```

Comment: Well, I guess I do need the id. It makes sense. Why did you include 'If you don't need an ID' part, if you know that I need an ID?

Comment: @MikeDunnegan I don't know if you need an id. There are cases where you don't need an id. E.g. if the logged in user can only update his own record, you don't need an id. Apparently you *do* need an id, so you should change your form so that it `puts` to `/employees/:id`.

Comment: Awesome, that last little bit about the form fixed it. Thanks a bunch, man

Comment: Well now, it seems that the attributes (specifically email) are not being updated. So close...

Comment: Can you see the mail attribute being sent in the log? Is mail `attr_accessible`?

Comment: I got it. I actually got rid of the employee update action. Instead, I just update the user, because each employee is a user, and I might as well go through devise, since i can